# CSS value is different in IE and Chrome

Tags: css, style.css

Is there reason why CSS id has a different value when you inspect element via IE or  CHrome, eg the max-width is set for my alternate css is 550px but when in Chrome its not showing as such but for IE its correct.

Comment: You can't rely on ids that are dynamically generated

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint generate some elements style dynamically. As IE and Chrome render HTML elements differently. Can help you more when you share some code. Which SharePoint version you have.